# Java package Log4J2: MapFilters

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I've got a simple question about MapFilters. Well, I know what maps are: simple key,value-pairs. Now log4j allows to filter for so called map messages by (**Example from website**):

```
  <MapFilter onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" operator="or">
    <KeyValuePair key="eventId" value="Login"/>
    <KeyValuePair key="eventId" value="Logout"/>
  </MapFilter>
```

But where do I define these messages in the code. I tried sth like:

```
    MapMessage mm = new MapMessage();
    mm.put("eventId", "Login");
    logger.exit(mm);
```

But this isn't rather a convenient way to handle this and by the way: It doesn't work.

Do you know a more detailed introduction into this topic? The API doesn't really help me here.

Thanks to you all!

Answer (score 3):

I came across the above issue while configuring `MapFilter`.
`ThreadContextMapFilter` works in the similar fashion but in that case we have to populate `ThreadContext` map and everything works fine.
The reason behind the success with `ThreadContextMapFilter` is `ThreadContext` map is Context based and it is valid for all the log events in the same context, but `MapFilter` which works on the basis of `MapMessage` is not context based (MapMessage) rather it is event based, so with each logging event we got to pass the `MapMessage` as parameter for the `MapFilter` to work.

The relevant configuration and code:

```
<configuration status="WARN" name="abcd">
    <properties/>
    <MapFilter onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY">
        <KeyValuePair key="Mic" value="Mic123"/>
    </MapFilter>                 
        ...........
        ........... <<Put other relevant configurations here>>
</configuration>
```

Java code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    MapMessage mapMessage = new MapMessage();

    mapMessage.put("Mic", "Mic123");
    log4j2Tester.logger.debug(mapMessage,new Exception("Okies"));
    log4j2Tester.logger.debug(mapMessage);
}
```

In the above code, `log4j2Tester` is the object of my standalone class and `logger` is the configured logger.

Hope this post will solve your problem.
Happy Coding.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you solution. I will try your hints in the next time.